# How do I calculate $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{s}{s^{\alpha}(s^{2}+1)}\right]$?

Tags: fractional-calculus, inverse-laplace

I was solving some problems of fractional calculus, and needed this intermediate result. How do I calculate $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{s}{s^{\alpha}(s^{2}+1)}\right]$?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you facing problems? We can help beter if you include these

Comment: http://wolframalfa.com can find inverse laplace transform.

Comment: Thanks  Mariusz Iwaniuk.